# How to do find-and-replace that respects character encoding?

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, replace, character-encoding

The copyright notices in our software need bumping up to 2014. This means:

1. Opening each file (in or below the working directory) called `AssemblyInfo.cs`
2. Replacing any line containing 'AssemblyCopyright' with the full line below.

> [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014 Company")]

Sounds a perfect little task to automate. I wrote a Python 3 script, but it mullered (ie. mojibaked) the copyright symbol. I guess this is due to character encoding issues.

So, how to do an encoding-respecting find-and-replace? That changes the copyright line without changing the file encoding.

My unreliable script was Python, but I don't mind using another language (C#, Ruby, Nodejs whatever) so long as it works.

---

For the curious, this was my Python script.

```
#!python
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
  for filename in filenames:
    if filename != 'AssemblyInfo.cs':
        continue
    path = os.path.join(root, filename)

    with open(path) as f:
        lines = list(f)

    new_lines = list()
    changed = False

    for line in lines:
        if "AssemblyCopyright" in line:
            line = '[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2014 Company")]\r\n'
            changed = True

        new_lines.append(line)

    if not changed:
        continue

    print(path)

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write("".join(new_lines))
```

Comment: In which encoding are the .cs files? Why don't you specify the exact encoding when reading and writing it?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I don't know, how can I tell?

Comment: Ask the one who created them. Or use `file` or any other tool that tells you which encoding it is. Or some magic library to detect the encoding.